# JavaScript/JQuery Garbage Collection and Events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, garbage-collection

Lets say I have this JQuery code which selects and gets an element by it's ID and than puts `click` event to it:

```
$( "someID" ).click( dummyCallback );
```

Later in the code I remove this element from the DOM by using `replaceWith()` or `remove()` functions.

```
$( "someID" ).replaceWith( "<div>New Element</div>" );
```

So this element will disappear from the DOM but what about the event that was bind to it?
As I understand events are also objects and take up space in memory.

Will JavaScript/JQuery also clean up that object(s) as well or before removing the element I should do:

```
$( "someID" ).off( "click" );
```

Comment: In theory, yes. jQuery does its best to destroy all resources which are no longer used when things like `remove()`, `off()`, `empty()` etc are called, however it is mostly dependant on the JavaScript implementation of the browser you're using as to whether that memory is marked as available again.

Comment: One of the core architectural goals of jQuery (historically, at least) was to prevent memory leak issues, particular in old versions of Internet Explorer.

Comment: _In addition to the elements themselves, all bound events and jQuery data associated with the elements are removed_ ([ref.](http://api.jquery.com/remove/))

Comment: Thank you for these great answers, I cant believe how fast you guys are. @hindmost yes I see it now, it is right there in the JQuery documentation for remove() and also for replaceWith() functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not worry about memory leaks if you remove element with dedicated methods like `remove`, `replaceWith`, `html`, etc. Those methods jQuery calles [`$.cleanData`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/62d5579578109f1468a37e44f76af06f283a46ab/src/manipulation.js#L246) method.

For example, for [replaceWith](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/62d5579578109f1468a37e44f76af06f283a46ab/src/manipulation.js#L404) you can see that jQuery removes events and data objects from internal cache in order to prevent leaks:

```
if ( jQuery.inArray( this, ignored ) < 0 ) {
    jQuery.cleanData( getAll( this ) );
    if ( parent ) {
        parent.replaceChild( elem, this );
    }
}
```

Of course, you should never remove elements with pure DOM methods if those elements has jQuery event listeners/data associated with them.

Comment: Thanks dfsq for the great answer and links.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is just a wrapper for native JavaScript functions. Anything you can do in jQuery you can do in JavaScript.

```
$( "someID" ).click( dummyCallback );
```

Boils down to:

```
document.getElementById("someID").addEventListener("click", dummyCallback, true);
// or the equivalent in older browsers
```

So how does the browser deal with event listeners on removed DOM elements? The simple answer is that it cleans them up, provided they are not otherwise referenced. You don't need to manually remove the event.

You can (accidentally or intentionally) keep a reference to either the DOM element (even if it is removed from the DOM) or the event handler. Keeping the reference will keep that code in memory.

It's useful to know that even if you keep a reference to the event handler, the DOM node can still be cleaned up, but the reverse is not true.

Comment: Thanks Halcyon that was what I wanted to know basically.